# How to use opencv c++ discrete cosine transform?

Tags: c++, opencv, dct

I have been working on a project involving getting the dct coefficients of an image and then store them in a list. The problem is that after I get the coefficients and put them in the list, then from that list I apply the inverse transform I do not get the image back. I do not  make any modifications to the coefficients. Below is the code I've written, I would like to know where is my mistake or how I can improve it so it gives back the image.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

void Image2ByteList(cv::Mat img, std::vector<unsigned char>& byteList){

byteList.resize(img.rows * img.cols);

for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
    {
        int k = i * img.cols + j;
        byteList[k] = img.at<unsigned char>(i, j);
        k++;
    }
}

std::ofstream fout("Image2List.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < byteList.size(); i++)
{
    fout << (int)byteList[i] << " ";
}
}

void byteList2Image(std::vector<unsigned char> byteList, cv::Mat& img, int rows, int cols)
{
cv::Size dims(0, 0);
dims.height = rows;
dims.width = cols;

cv::Mat newMat(dims, CV_8UC1);

for (int k = 0; k < byteList.size(); k++)
{
    newMat.at<unsigned char>(k / cols, k % cols) = byteList[k];
}

img = newMat.clone();
}


void function()
{
cv::Mat img, imgGray, imgConv, DCT, DCTconv, recoverDCT, recoverDCTconv, recoverImg;

img = cv::imread("jpg_44.jpg");

cv::cvtColor(img, imgGray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

imgGray.convertTo(imgConv, CV_32FC1);

cv::dct(imgConv, DCT);

DCT.convertTo(DCTconv, CV_8UC1);

std::vector<unsigned char> coeffsList;

Image2ByteList(DCTconv, coeffsList);

byteList2Image(coeffsList, recoverDCT, DCTconv.rows, DCTconv.cols);

recoverDCT.convertTo(recoverDCTconv, CV_32FC1);

cv::idct(recoverDCTconv, recoverImg);

cv::imwrite("Test.jpg", recoverImg);
 }

int main()
{
 function();

  return 0;
}
```

The images are:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EbdE.jpg) before
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmhNv.jpg) after

Comment: reduce your code until it works. then you know what part causes the issue.

Comment: If I use only dct it works. The Image2ByteList and byteList2Image work fine but when I combine them then it doesnt work.

Comment: use dct and idct without your own custom functions. does that work, or does it not?

Comment: The code does not compile.  The code needs `#include <cryptopp/config_int.h>` and there's a typo in `unsined`.  Why do you waste someone else's time? Please edit these, and also add some hints on how to compile the code.